# Form pivot table for more than two dynamic column

Tags: sql-server

I have created this table

```
CREATE TABLE [DPI]
(
    [ClientCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [RunDater] [date] NULL,
    [Debit] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Credit] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [DayOfDifference] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Interest] [numeric](18, 2) NULL
 )
```

Inserted values:

```
 INSERT INTO DPI (ClientCode, RunDater, Debit, Credit, DayOfDifference, Interest) 
 VALUES 
 ('Z001','20/01/2001',20,0,0,18)
 ,('Z001','21/01/2001',0,0,0 ,0)
 ,('Z001','22/01/2001',40,20,0 ,0)
 ,('Z001','23/01/2001',0,0,0,0)
 ,('Z001','24/01/2001',0,20,0 ,0)
 ,('Z001','25/01/2001',100,0,0,0)
 ,('Z001','26/01/2001',0,0,0,0)
 ,('Z002','20/01/2001',0,0 ,0,0)
 ,('Z002','21/01/2001',0,0,0,0)
 ,('Z002','22/01/2001',30,20,0,0)
 ,('Z002','23/01/2001',0,0,0 ,0)
 ,('Z002','24/01/2001',0,20,0,0)
  ,('Z002','25/01/2001',100,0,0,0)
 ,('Z002','26/01/2001',0,0,0,0)
```

I wrote this query for getting the running balance and store in temporary table:

```
SELECT 
    *, SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientCode ORDER BY RunDater) AS Amount
INTO #temp 
FROM DPI AS Amount
```

Now my table looks like this:

[image]

and want output in this format:

[image]

Comment: "and want output in this format". I don't understand what exactly your are asking, i.e. what is the key difference between the two tables you posted?

Answer (score 3):

Does the following code fulfill your requirement?

```
SELECT 
    *, SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientCode ORDER BY RunDater) AS Amount
INTO #temp 
FROM DPI AS Amount

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((select distinct ', 
            SUM(CASE WHEN [RunDater]=''' + CAST([RunDater] as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN [Interest] ELSE 0 END) AS [' + CAST([RunDater] as varchar(10)) + ' Interest],
            SUM(CASE WHEN [RunDater]=''' + CAST([RunDater] as varchar(10)) + ''' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS [' + CAST([RunDater] as varchar(10)) + ' Amount]'
            /*---------------You can add other columns here similar to above--------------*/
            FROM #temp 
            FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')
SET @query = 'SELECT ClientCode, ' + @Cols + '  FROM #temp group by ClientCode' 

--print (@query)
exec(@query)
```

[**dbfiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3e300dc2e4961ec64ef5e903bf73304)

Comment: very nice!  prob a good idea to put the code in the answer tho.

Comment: i actually prefer @sacse 's answer!

Comment: but sir order of Rundater is not arranged properly

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) the RunDater columns and show the Interest per ClientCode.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(RunDater)
               FROM DPI
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') 

SET @query = 'SELECT ClientCode
,' + @cols + ' FROM
(
   SELECT ClientCode, RunDater, Interest
   FROM DPI  
) x
PIVOT 
(
   MAX(Interest)
   FOR RunDater IN (' + @cols + ')
) p '

execute(@query)
```